# “another book about AI” vs “a different book about AI”

Tags: meaning, word-usage

<sub>Disclaimer: I hope my question isn't a duplicate.</sub>

The determiner "another" appears ambiguous in certain contexts to non-native speakers of English.

Let's suppose I bought a book about artificial intelligence.

I bought the book because it was what I thought I was looking for. After going through the book, I realized it was not what I wanted. After that, I decided to buy a new one, still about artificial intelligence.

---

**Question**

- Am I buying *another* book or a *different* book?
- In other words, am I buying a second book or a replacement of the existing one?

Comment: Aren't you doing both?

Comment: It's ambiguous for native speakers, too. When I was a child I had the book [*Mother, Mother, I want another*](https://www.amazon.com/Mother-I-Want-Another/dp/0517559471/) where baby Mouse keeps getting replacement mothers when all he wants is an additional kiss from his mother.

Comment: Both **another** and **different** doesn't imply that you replaced it or kept it.

Comment: If you buy "another" book the implication is that you are buying a second one, in addition to the first. If you buy a "different" book, it suggests it is an alternative to buying the first one (which you will be retuning). But both words leave some room for ambiguity.

Comment: Because it's potentially ambiguous, a little common sense is needed. Why would you buy a second copy of a book you didn't want? *Another* must mean that you bought a different book. There is no information about whether you returned the first: you may have done, but you might equally have kept it. (If you bought the same book again, you would be buying ***another copy.***)

Comment: Does it mean then that it wouldn't make sense if I say "I'll buy 'another' book" even if I didn't like the first one whereas it would if I say "I'll buy a 'different' book" when I didn't like the first one?

Comment: @AndrewLeach Introducing the idea of a second copy of the same book, merely adds further complication and more room for ambiguity. The question was not about that. "After going through the book" the OP decided it was not the one he wanted.  So he buys "another" book, which is also a "different" book. But what I am saying is that the choice of whether to say "another" or whether to say "different" provides a clue as to how many books he took home from the shop - but only a clue because neither word is conclusive about how many books he bought.

Comment: @WS2 OP himself introduced the idea of *another* meaning "another copy"; I was simply saying that *another* doesn't usually mean "another copy" where it would be, um, odd to buy another copy. That ambiguity is what makes the question interesting.

Comment: The way to say what you want is to say that you bought "yet another" book on AI.

Comment: @Xanne "Yet another" for a second book is not standard. Why would one use this?

Answer (score 1):

"After going through the book" the OP decided it was not the one he wanted. So he buys "another" book, which is also a "different" book (nothing in the question suggests a second copy of the same book).

The choice of whether to say "another" or whether to say "different" could provide a clue as to whether he ended up just buying one book, or two books.

"Another" could suggest that he ended up with two books. "Different" could imply that he returned his original purchase. But both words allow for some ambiguity as to how many books were bought.